# free shipping of a single product in magento

Tags: magento

i'm using magento version 1.3.2.4

I want to change a product shipping as free shipping. All other products will be charged for shipping. for this i have done the following steps

Here’s what I did to offer free shipping on one specific product:
First, turn on Free Shipping in your **Admin Panel > System > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods > Free Shipping**.

**VERY IMPORTANT:** set a bogus Minimum order amount – I used 9999999999.99 because if someone spends that much at my shop in one go, I’m retiring.
Save Config.

Second, go to **Admin Panel > Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules**.

```
Add New Rule.
Use these exact settings:
Rule Name: free shipping
Description: free shipping
Status: Active
Customer Groups: selected all
Coupon Code: [blank]
Uses Per Coupon: 0
Uses Per Customer: 0
From Date: [today]
Priority: 0
Public in RSS Feed: No 
Conditions: [ignored this section]
Actions:
Apply: Fixed amount discount
Discount Amount: 0
Minimum Qty Discount is Applied to: 0
Discount Qty Step (Buy X): 0
Free Shipping: For shipment with matching rule
Stop further rules processing: No
Apply the rule … :
If ALL of these conditions are TRUE:
SKU is [inserted specific SKU]
```

.
Saved Rule.

this is working for me, but when i first add the product with free shipping, free shipping option is coming, then again when i add another product with shipping, at that point shipping option will come.
upto this point its ok.

but in the final checkout page no shipping is there. Actually one product is with shipping and other is without shipping, so it must be like that.

how can i solve this issue

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution grants free shipping to an entire order, so that may not work in the way you want. Depending on which shipping services you are using, you could go the hack route of setting the weight to 0, so that FedEx and the like won't count it in shipping calculations.

Otherwise, can you provide more detail on your shipping configuration (other than the free shipping)?

Answer (score 2):

This is covered for magento 1.3 at length here: [magento free shipping](http://www.immense.net/magento-free-shipping-certain-products/)

Answer (score -1):

:) look, there is a solution that is much, much simpler :)

under "Catalog" create a new product ("Add Product") and for the "Product Type" choose "Virtual Product".

that's it :) enjoy a product with £0.00 shipping costs.

here is a link to a screenshot (apparently I am new member here and can't post images yet):

```
http://screencast.com/t/dOmkV3KBkZ
```

be well,
Helmuts

p.s. made this explanation longer for the needs of those who don't know magento at all.